# Does polymer has some official animation components like neon-animation which now has been deprecated?

Tags: animation, polymer-2.x, office-web-components

[webcomponents info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMkoi.png)

My project developed with polymer.I just find [neon-animation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/neon-animation) component has been deprecated.Some alternative components are available ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although `neon-animation` has been deprecated, it will still be around for some time. However, Polymer's mission has always been *"use the platform"*, and as such, for new Projects it is recommended to use what the platform has to offer in terms of animations.

> If you're creating a new element from scratch, we recommend using CSS
>   keyframe animations, CSS transitions, or the Web Animations API.

You can read the update on neon-animations [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2017-07-12-an-update-on-neon-animation).

Comment: Thanks for your kind advice, but what does "use the platform" mean? It means [webcomponents](https://www.webcomponents.org/) ?

Comment: "Use the Platform" is Polymer's motto and mission. It means, use as much of what the platform (the browser and the standards around web) already offer. Like native custom elements, leveraging the DOM, events and attributes for data transportation, etc. Take a look at this: https://www.polymer-project.org/about